# Xcode 8.2 Swift Compiler Error: "Segmentation Fault: 11"

Tags: swift, xcode, generics, compiler-errors, segmentation-fault

This function works correctly when I don't implement it generically (just with ints), but when I go to make it generic, changing only a few letters with no obvious errors, Swift is unable to compile it; I don't even use the func, simply having the file in my project crashes it.

Xcode says that "an internal error has occurred." I checked the stack trace, and the error is listed as "Segmentation Fault: 11." I'll post my code below.

I can also post the stack trace upon request.

```
import Foundation

func BinSearch<T : Comparable>(elements: [T], target: T) -> Int?{
    let maxIndex = elements.count - 1
    var rightIndex = maxIndex
    var leftIndex = 0
    var middleIndex : Int {return lround(Double((rightIndex + leftIndex)) / 2)}

    var maxVal : T {return elements[rightIndex]}
    var middleVal : T {return elements[middleIndex]}
    var minVal : T {return elements[leftIndex]}

    while elements[middleIndex] != target {
        //test if in infinite loop for target within range of array but DNE
        if leftIndex == middleIndex || rightIndex == middleIndex && rightIndex != 1{
            return nil
        }

        //prevent infinite loop due to rounding method
        if rightIndex == 1 {
            return leftIndex
        }

        //core code
        if target > middleVal {
            leftIndex = middleIndex
        }else {
            rightIndex = middleIndex
        }
    }
    return middleIndex
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The compiler should not crash, no matter how "wrong" the source code is,
so you might consider to file a bug report.

In this case, the problem seems to be that `middleVal` is a computed
property. If you replace

```
    //core code
    if target > middleVal {
        leftIndex = middleIndex
    }else {
        rightIndex = middleIndex
    }
```

by

```
    //core code
    if target > elements[middleIndex] {
        leftIndex = middleIndex
    }else {
        rightIndex = middleIndex
    }
```

then the code compiles. However, it does not work correctly.
For example

```
 BinSearch(elements: [3, 4, 5], target: 2)
```

returns `0` instead of `nil`. (Also I see no advantage in using
computed properties for `middleIndex` and `middleVal`. 
`maxVal` and `minVal` are not used at all in your code.)

Here is an example of a correctly working implementation
(inspired by http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Binary_search#Swift):

```
func binarySearch<T : Comparable>(elements: [T], target: T) -> Int? {
    var leftIndex = 0
    var rightIndex = elements.count - 1

    while leftIndex <= rightIndex {
        let middleIndex = (leftIndex + rightIndex) / 2
        if elements[middleIndex] < target {
            leftIndex = middleIndex + 1 // Continue search in upper half.
        } else if target < elements[middleIndex] {
            rightIndex = middleIndex - 1 // Continue search in lower half.
        } else {
            return middleIndex // Found.
        }
    }
    return nil // Not found.
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In my case I got this error when using `typealias` in old Swift 2 format in a Swift 3 environment, for instance :

`(Void -> Void)`
instead of 
`(() -> ())`